# SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter; says mSectionsPagerAdapter cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter; says mSectionsPagerAdapter cannot be resolved to a variable.

It doesn't not give me any suggestions for inputs.

Comment: rebuild.
check imports.

Comment: nope, any other suggestions? is SectionsPagerAdapter an import that should appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a referenced variable of inner class **SectionsPagerAdapter**, which extends the **FragmentPAgerAdapter** class, basically handling the swipe or click functions on a View pager(simply actions on Tabs or swiping on fragments).

[image]

possible errors could be -

1. Inner class not defined.
2. Error in naming of inner class and the
   variable data type.

Comment: I've tried a number of things and still Eclipse doesnt like my mSectionPagerAdapter, heres a screenshot, any ideas? http://i.imgur.com/8WLjJA3.png

Comment: See the name of inner class it is *SectionPagerAdapter*, while for variable data-type you are using *SectionsPagerAdapter*. The missing 's'.